# Lumia 535 not receiving notifications for Viber and Skype

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, skype, viber

I cannot receive calls or notifications for Viber and Skype unless I connect to the application and go online.  Even then, I receive nothing once on screen lock.  Strangely, these apps also do not appear in my Action Centre.

Comment: Check if you have disabled the notifications in the applications.

Comment: maybe, you can try reinstalling them?